# Regular expression pattern match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to extract from a string containing html content, text between the first occurrence of (`<a>` and `<span>` tags).

My pattern is as following :

```
$pattern='/<a[^(span)][\/\(\)-:@!%*>#=_|?$&";.\w\s]+<\/a> <span/um';
```

I get the output as text between 1st occurrence of `<a` and last occurrence of `<span` and not text between 1st occurrence of both.

eg, html content:

```
<a href="#">asdasdasd</a> <span blah blah></span> blah blah <a>blah  </a> <span>blah
```

Want:

```
<a href="#">asdasdasd</a> <span
```

Getting:

```
<a href="#">asdasdasd</a> <span blah blah></span> blah blah <a>blah  </a> <span
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question by I would suggest not using regex parse html. Why not try something like this [dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and save some time.

Comment: Know dom parsers but using regex cause have to in a assignment. learning regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a HTML parser for parsing HTML
2. Use lazy quantifier `'/<a[^(span)][\/\(\)-:@!%*>#=_|?$&";.\w\s]+?<\/a> <span/um';`

Comment: Thanks buddy..!! that helped...!! new with regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the regular expression lazy rather than greedy by telling it to match as few characters between `<a` and `<span` as possible with `.+?`:

```
$ptn = '/<a.+?<span/';
$str = '<a href="#">asdasdasd</a> <span blah blah></span> blah blah <a>blah  </a> <span>blah';
preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

The result is `<a href=\"#\">asdasdasd</a> <span`

Comment: Thanks buddy..!! that helped...!! new with regular expressions